# didUpdateLocations not getting called in the background (obj-c)

Tags: ios, objective-c, unity-game-engine

I am writing an IOS plugin for our existing Unity app, to check and send location updates to our server both in foreground and background. I managed to get the location updates when the app is in the foreground, but for some reason it won't call "didUpdateLocations" when the app is in the background. Here is my code for setting up location services:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <CoreLocation/CoreLocation.h>
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface IOSPlugin :NSObject <CLLocationManagerDelegate>
@property (strong, nonatomic) CLLocationManager *locationManager;
@end

@implementation IOSPlugin
@synthesize locationManager;

static IOSPlugin *_sharedInstance;
static NSString * token;

+(IOSPlugin *) sharedInstance
{
    static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
    dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
        NSLog(@"Creating IOSPlugin shared instance");
        _sharedInstance = [[IOSPlugin alloc] init];
    });
    return _sharedInstance;
}

-(id)init
{
    self = [super init];
    if(self)
        [self setup];
    return self;
}

-(void)setup
{
    locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
    locationManager.delegate = self;
    locationManager.distanceFilter = kCLDistanceFilterNone;
    locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyHundredMeters;
    locationManager.allowsBackgroundLocationUpdates = YES;

    if([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] floatValue] >= 8.0)
    {
        [locationManager requestAlwaysAuthorization];
    }

    NSLog(@"LocationManager initalised..");

}

-(void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager 
didUpdateLocations:(NSArray<CLLocation *> *)locations
{
    NSLog(@"%f", locations.lastObject.coordinate.latitude);
    NSLog(@"%f", locations.lastObject.coordinate.longitude);

    CLLocation* loc = locations.lastObject;

    //show a toast just to see if this gets called
    [_sharedInstance showMessage];
    //send location to server
    [_sharedInstance sendToApi:loc];
}
```

I have 2 methods that are switching between foreground and background location services (the token being passed through is just for our server):

```
-(void)startForegroundLocationService:(NSString *)_token
{
    token = _token;
    
    [locationManager stopMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges];
    NSLog(@"Stopped background location service");

    [locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
    NSLog(@"Started foreground location service");
}

-(void)startBackgroundLocationService:(NSString *)_token
{
    token = _token;
    
    [locationManager stopUpdatingLocation];
    NSLog(@"Stopped foreground location service");

    [locationManager startMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges];
    NSLog(@"Started background location service");
}
```

These are called from unity in a C# script, when the application gets backgrounded it calls startBackgroundLocationService and vice versa.

I also have a post-build C# script that edits the plist file to add to the following keys:

```
NSLocationAlwaysAndWhenInUseUsageDescription - "Uses background location"
NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription - "Uses foreground location"
UIBackgroundModes - "location"
```

This implementation works wonderfully when the app is open, in simulator or on device if I change locations it will send it to our server and it's great. When the application gets backgrounded, there are no callbacks received by the didUpdateLocations method that I can see, and it doesn't send anything to our server.

Comment: Post the body of `sendToApi` method. Also, is `CLLocationManagerDelegate` method  `didFailWithError` called? Also, are you sure `didUpdateLocations` is never called, or is just remote service not receiving anything? Because the problem might lie somewhere else.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I figured it out, in order to get it working in the background I had to use "startUpdatingLocatin" again after I call "startMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges" for some reason, and now it works in the background. Now i'm just having an issue with getting it working when the app is terminated

Answer (score 0):

I see that you got background location updates working but you can't get location updates working when the app is terminated.

[From the Apple Docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corelocation/cllocationmanager/1423531-startmonitoringsignificantlocati?language=objc):

> If you start this service and your app is subsequently terminated, the
> system automatically relaunches the app into the background if a new
> event arrives. In such a case, the options dictionary passed to the
> application:willFinishLaunchingWithOptions: and
> application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: methods of your app
> delegate contains the key UIApplicationLaunchOptionsLocationKey to
> indicate that your app was launched because of a location event. Upon
> relaunch, you must still configure a location manager object and call
> this method to continue receiving location events. When you restart
> location services, the current event is delivered to your delegate
> immediately. In addition, the location property of your location
> manager object is populated with the most recent location object even
> before you start location services.

So in your App Delegate, make sure to recreate and configure your location manager in the `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` method if the `UIApplicationLaunchOptionsLocationKey` key is present.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I already posted a separate question for my issue with termination, where I'm using the functions that you have mentioned:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53543200/obj-c-unity-app-not-receiving-callback-to-didfinishlaunchingwithoptions-when